# Is it possible to make a webm file use a custom duration that is not the actual video's duration? And if so how?

Tags: video, webm

Someone showed me a video where the duration counter would keep changing and another where there was a negative number as the duration, is there anyway to reproduce this? Both were webm files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a proper answer to this, using the program MKVToolNix you can find the hex position of the duration and using a hex editor, you can change a certain number of bytes (MKVToolNix will tell you how long it is) to change the duration to whatever number you want

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you got more metadata options on .webm files.

Opening it with notepad/txt you can see some duration changes?[dc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iomyQ.png)

located at the top.

Not sure how they found this program, but it seems pretty easy to change the time, on it if just you get the right program.